# In docker I can not login into phppgadmin

Tags: docker, phppgadmin

I make in docker php/postgres app with phppgadmin  and I have problems that I can not
login in phppgadmin and got error

```
Invalid login
```

I have:

```
version: '3'

services:

    web:
        build:
            context: ./web       
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000

        container_name: lprods_web

        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8086:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}



    db:
        image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
        container_name: lprods_db
        ports:
            - '5433:5432' // THAT IS USED PORT 
        restart: always
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '1'
            POSTGRES_DB: 'wprods' // I NEED TO CREATE THIS BD in phppgadmin
        volumes:
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


    phppgadmin:
        image: dockage/phppgadmin:latest
        environment:
            - POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgres
            # - POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
            - POSTGRESQL_PORT='5433:5432' // THAT IS USED PORT
            - POSTGRESQL_DEFAULT_DB=postgres
        container_name: lprods_phppgadmin

        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8087:80
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - db
```

I see in console:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
709b563331fc        dockage/phppgadmin:latest   "/sbin/entrypoint ap"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8087->80/tcp   lprods_phppgadmin
6d5df00a25be        lprodsdocker_web            "docker-php-entrypoi"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp                         lprods_web
0751d16f728f        postgres:9.6.10-alpine      "docker-entrypoint.s"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp                       lprods_db
```

Why I can not login in phppgadmin ?
I think I entered valid password. Can I check it somehow ?

Comment: try o connect to your DB using the username and password from the command line inside the db container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables names for [`dockage/phppgadmin`](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockage/phppgadmin/) are wrong, as well as the host/port values that you are setting.

You need to set them like this:

```
    phppgadmin:
        image: dockage/phppgadmin:latest
        environment:
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST=db
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT=5432
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_DEFAULT_DB=postgres
```

Then you can login on phpPgAdmin by using the user `postgres` with password `1`.